# How to compare letters from a input string to letters in a a different string from a given list?

Tags: python, list

Hi I'm trying to make a word game, where the user guesses a word from a word in a given list, and the program tells the user what words they got wrong. The problem I'm having is that my program does not check for the words that the user inputs, but instead checks the validity of the word from the word list. How do I check each letter in the string to see whether it matches to the corresponding letter in the word from the given list?

```
def checkLetters(secretWord, userWord):

    print ("The word is " + secretWord)

    for  i in range(0,len(secretWord)):
        while secretWord[0] ==  userWord[0].lower():
            print(str(i) + "is Correct")
            break
    for i in secretWord:
        if secretWord[0] != userWord[0].lower():
            print(str(userWord[i]) + " is false")


import random
validWords = ["could", "smile", "ultra", "extra","beacon", "hearts", "cap","computing", "python"]
wordPosition = random.randint(0,len(validWords)-1)
guess = input("Enter Your guess for the word: ")


checkLetters(validWords[wordPosition], guess)
```

Comment: Are you trying to check whether the user got the entire *word* wrong, or whether they got individual *letters* wrong?  If you're trying to tell them letter by letter, what do you want to do when their guess is a different length from the answer?  Some sample input and output would be very useful in clarifying what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check letter by letter to see if user input matches random word from a given list:

```py
def checkLetters(secretWord, userWord):
    print(f'Secret word: {secretWord}, user word: {userWord}')
    if len(secretWord) != len(userWord):
        return False

    for i, letter in enumerate(secretWord):
        if letter != userWord[i]:
            return False 
    
    return True


import random
validWords = ["could", "smile", "ultra", "extra","beacon", "hearts", "cap","computing", "python"]
wordPosition = random.randint(0,len(validWords)-1)
guess = input("Enter Your guess for the word: ")


result = checkLetters(validWords[wordPosition], guess)
print(result)
```

Comment: enumarate() will give you pair (index, character) in for loop